# How to add custom option in the datatable's dropdown column filtering

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a jquery datatable and in this datatable I have added a dropdown column filtering. In this filter option, it shows only those options which are present on this page. As this column could have two different value at max. So, instead of showing the total options from that page, I want to show custom option.

My current code looks like:

```
let company_id = '<?php echo $company->id; ?>';
var table = $('#companyUsersDatatable').DataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": {
        "url":base_path +'/admin/company/'+company_id+'/users/list',
        "dataType":"json",
        "type":"POST",
        "data":{"_token":csrf_token}
    },
    "initComplete": function () {
        this.api().columns([3]).every( function () {
            var column = this;
            var select = $('<select class="form-control"><option value="1">Admin</option><option value="2">User</option></select>')
                .appendTo( $(column.footer()).empty() )
                .on( 'change', function () {
                    var val = $(this).val();
                    column.search( this.value ).draw();
                } );

            // Only contains the *visible* options from the first page
            // console.log(column.data().unique());

            // If I add extra data in my JSON, how do I access it here besides column.data?
            column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
            } );
        } );
    },
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            'targets': 0,
            'checkboxes': {
                'selectRow': true
            }
        }
    ],
    "select": {
        'style': 'multi'
    },
    "columns":[
        {"data":"id"},
        {"data":"name"},
        {"data":"email"},
        {"data":"company_role"},
        {"data":"created_at"},
        {"data":"action","searchable":false,"orderable":false}
    ],
    "deferRender": true,
    "pagingType": "simple",
    "searchable": false,
    // "bFilter": false,
    // "searching": true,
    // "ordering": false,
    "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]],
    "dom": "lrtip",
    "language": {
        "emptyTable": " "
    }
});
```

However, this code displays not only two desired options of `Admin` and `users` but also the additional options from the value of the `company_role` column.

My need is to show two dropdown options only with `admin` and `user`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are the additional options valid values for that column? Why then do you say that this column could have a maximum of two values? Do you want to display the additional values in your column but not be able to filter by them?